# An android mobile tablet browser emulator?

Tags: android, browser, mobile, tablet

What is the best android/mobile/tablet browser emulator i can use to test some html5 stuff on?

I dont want to have to download all the sdk stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the SDK stuff and use the appropriate API level and screen resolution, that is the best (and only as far as I know) way.

Comment: Check also this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464089/simulators-emulators-for-mobile-browser-testing

Answer (score 0):

I normally use this - http://www.browserstack.com/mobile-browser-emulator

Its one of the cheapest around and supports pretty much all the possible browser resolutions and stuff..